# GItLab EE : Sign in/Sign up pages Logo was not reflected

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce, gitlab-ee

I need some help.
I uploaded a logo for custom sign-in on GitLab, but the logo does not reflect, is there any chance/details that I missed this?

**config**

[image]

**preview**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to a bug since the new "Streamlined sign-in page" was introduced in 15.4.

[There is a feedback issue for the redesign ...](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/372425)

[... and an issue regarding the hardcoded Logo](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/375269)

There is already a MR for a fix to be implemented in 15.5 or you could set
the "restyle_login_page" feature to go back to the old style login for a workaround.

**Edit: Issue is fixed in 15.5.0**